# Can't recreate child gameObjects unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a ScrollView with child buttons and Text objects which are dynamically created by the script. For the first time, the buttons and text are created normally, but when you try to destroy the ScrollView, and add buttons and text to it, they are not created again.

```
if (GameObject.Find("ScrollViewUsers") != null)
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("ScrollViewUsers"));
    }

    GameObject scrollView = Instantiate(GameObject.Find("ScrollViewUsersSample"), GameObject.Find("PanelFindFriends").transform, true);
    scrollView.name = "ScrollViewUsers";
    scrollView.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(0, -20, 0);
    scrollView.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(GameObject.Find("PanelFindFriends").GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x, GameObject.Find("PanelFindFriends").GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y - 40);
    scrollView.transform.Find("Viewport/ContentUsersSample").name = "ContentUsers";

    Debug.Log("userList.Count=" + userList.Count);
    float _y = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> user in userList)
    {
        Debug.Log("user=" + user.Value);
        Instantiate(GameObject.Find("TextUser"), GameObject.Find("ContentUsers").transform, true);
        GameObject.Find("TextUser(Clone)").name = "user_" + user.Value;
        GameObject.Find("user_" + user.Value).GetComponent<Text>().text = user.Value;
        GameObject.Find("user_" + user.Value).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(-25, y, 0);

        Instantiate(GameObject.Find("ButtonAddUser"), GameObject.Find("ContentUsers").transform, true);
        GameObject.Find("ButtonAddUser(Clone)").name = "addUser_" + user.Value;
        GameObject.Find("addUser_" + user.Value).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(62, y, 0);
        y -= 40;

        _y += (GameObject.Find("user_" + user.Value).GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y + 20);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to give you a tip: Use inspector assigned variables instead of GameObject.Find. It is very 'error prone' to find objects by name and also very expensive/ inefficient.
You should learn to use prefabs and instantiate instances of it.

Comment: Thx. can you gime me the sample of inspector assigned variables instead of GameObject

Comment: You should go through the [Instantiate Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/instantiate) ... and all those `Find` calls ... hmmmm

Comment: If you ever find yourself calling `GameObject.Find()` more than once, your doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of your required

```
List<string> userList = new List<string> { "User1", "User2", "User3" };

[SerializeField]
private Text TextUserPrefabRef;

[SerializeField]
private Button ButtonAddUserPrefabRef;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject ScrollViewUsersSamplePrefabRef;

[SerializeField]
private Transform PanelFindFriendsRef;

private Transform ContentUsers;

public void CreateNew () 
{
    if (GameObject.Find("ScrollViewUsers") != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Destroying");
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("ScrollViewUsers"));
    }

    GameObject scrollView = Instantiate(ScrollViewUsersSamplePrefabRef, PanelFindFriendsRef);
    scrollView.name = "ScrollViewUsers";

    ContentUsers = scrollView.transform.Find("Viewport/ContentUsersSample");
    ContentUsers.name = "ContentUsers";

    foreach (string user in userList)
    {
        Debug.Log("user=" + user);
        GameObject newTextUser = Instantiate (TextUserPrefabRef.gameObject, ContentUsers) as GameObject;
        newTextUser.GetComponent<Text>().text = user;

        GameObject newButton = Instantiate (ButtonAddUserPrefabRef.gameObject, ContentUsers);
        newButton.name = "addUser_" + user;
    }   
}
```

Then make prefabs of your scrollView, AddUserButton and Text Objects
And assign them in inspector.

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach loop, Create a new variable instead of the GameObject.Find().

e.g.:

```
var go = Instantiate(GameObject.Find("TextUser"), GameObject.Find("ContentUsers").transform, true);)
go.name = "...";
go.GetComponent<Text>().text = "...";
```

Comment: did as you said, but the buttons are still not created

Comment: You need check is there new object created in the Hierarchy. And as @Immorality said.use inspector assigned variables instead of Find GameObject.

Comment: sorry but im just started to lern unity. how to use inspector assigned variables instead of Find GameObject

Comment: `[SerializeField] private GameObject m_textUserObj;`
`[SerializeField] private Transform m_userListParent;`
`var go = Instantiate(m_textUserObj,m_userListParent,true);`

This is just a sample. add these lines of code, which will show you the assignment in the inspector.(Make sure your script is mounted on an object,I'm sorry my English is very poor).

Comment: @A_____ you should update additional instructions and examples into your answer not in the comments